# Send a serialized Custom object over the network via a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, network-programming, client-server

I'm writing a basic Server/Client code to send some custom objects over the network using sockets.

My custom object also has some other **already initialized** custom fields.
e.g
```

```
public class CustomObject implements Serializable {
    private ONE one = new ONE();        //ONE implements Serializeable
    private TWO two = new TWO();        //TWO implements Serializeable
    private THREE three = new THREE();  //THREE implements Serializeable
    String somestring = "piday";
    ....
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return somestring + one;
    }
}
```

```

On the **Client side**, I'm writing objects like this:
```

```
Socket s = new Socket(HOST,PORT);
new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())
    .writeObject(machine);
```

And receiving them on the **server** like the following:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
try (Socket s = server.accept();
     ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream())) {
            CustomObject machine = (CustomObject) inputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(machine);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Err! Could not cast");
        }
```

Now, on the server side everything runs with no errors or so, the thing is when I debug I see that *one,tow and three* custom objects  are ***NULL***, but not the basic string *somestring*!

What am I missing or doing wrong in this example, please?

***Note that*** ONE, TWO and THREE type definitions **do implement Serializable** too.
**AND**
All custom class definitions **are accessible to both the Server and the Client**.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the best ways is serialize our object first (to JSON or XML). Then convert this output string to bytes (optionally) and send it through sockets and on the other side, reverse these steps to get the object back.

This procedure allows you to implement encryption (if necessary) in the future also.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I'm doing it this way only for learning purposes.  I ran into this issue and I need to know what's wrong exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Java Serialization is an immensely powerful protocol. java.io.ObjectOutputStream and java.io.ObjectInputStream are the higher level classes which of course are wrapped with the lower level classes such as FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. My question is why do you wish to read the file byte by byte when the entire file can be read in Objects.

Here is a good explanation of the procedure.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.html